# How Finch validationRule apply for jsonBody?

Tags: scala, finch

I can Validation.

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int, email: String)

val mailRule = ValidationRule[String]("mail should be mailRule")("""(\w+)@([\w\.]+)""".r.unapplySeq(_).isDefined)

val child: Endpoint[User] = (
  param("name") ::
  param[Int]("age") ::
  param("email").should(mailRule) // ex testmail.com → I can receive the finchError 
).as[User
```

However, I do not know the validation apply when using jsonBody[User] below.
please help me.

```
val userJson:Endpoint[User] = jsonBody[User]
val createUserByJson: Endpoint[Int] = post("usersjson" :: userJson) { u: 
[User] =>
    ・・・
 }
```

I use library below

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.twitter" %% "finagle-mysql" % "18.3.0",
  "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-core" % "0.17.0",
  "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-argonaut" % "0.17.0",
  "com.twitter" %% "finagle-http" % "18.3.0",
  "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-circe" % "0.17.0",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.9.1",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.9.1",
  "ch.qos.logback"  %  "logback-classic"  % "1.1.3"
)
```